# Countdown timer error when changing inside my web page using Angular, TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I set a countdown timer in typescript to my webpage on the home page. But when I change to another page I get a console error every second.

> .TS

```
countDown() {
    var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 1, 2022 00:00:00").getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function () {
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Display the result in an element with id="demo"
      var contadorElement =  document.getElementById("contador") as HTMLElement; // <- Line 37
      contadorElement.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
        + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        contadorElement.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

> .HTML

```
<p id="contador" style="font-size:30px"></p>
```

The code above works under 'localhost:4200/'. However if I go to 'localhost:4200/anotherStuf' (for example) I get this console error every second:

```
core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at home.component.ts:37
    at timer (zone.js:2561)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28661)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:487)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:476)
    at data.args.<computed> (zone.js:2541)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change your page, the part of the DOM that your `contador` element resides in gets destroyed. Since you do not clean up your `setInterval` in the `ngOnDestroy` hook, your code is still running, even when you navigate away (i.e. your component gets destroyed). This would lead to an error along the lines of `cannot read undefined of contadorElement (reading: innerHTML)` or something similiar.

The solution is simple: clean up your `setInterval`, which you can achieve by calling `clearInterval` in the `ngOnDestroy` hook, using the return value of your `setInterval` as the parameter.

```js
private interval;

countDown() {
   this.interval = setTimeout(() => { /* Omitted for readability */}, 1000);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Since you are clearing the interval already when the distance reaches 0, you might want to polish this a bit by setting the variable to `undefined` or `null` after clearing the interval and only calling `clearInterval` when you did not already stop it.

```js
private interval;

countDown() {
   this.interval = setTimeout(() => { 
      /* Omitted for readability */
      
      if (distance < 0) {
        this.stopInterval();
        contadorElement.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
   }, 1000);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   clearInterval(this.interval);
}

private stopInterval() {
   if (this.interval) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.interval = null;
   }
}
```

If you can't stop the timer in `ngOnDestroy` (if, for example, your code resides inside a service and you don't want to call a `stopCountDown` method in `ngOnDestroy`), you will have to check if the element exists in each setInterval loop and possibly destroy the interval if it does not exist anymore.

```js
countDown() {

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function () {
      /* Omitted for readability */
       
      var contadorElement =  document.getElementById("contador") as HTMLElement; 

      if (contadorElement) {
         contadorElement.innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
      } else {
         clearInterval(x);
      }

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        contadorElement.innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```